# Calculate the value of $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\dfrac{n}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

In a previous question it is asked to represent $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1-x^2}$ as a power series.
It gave me $\displaystyle\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}x\left(2x^2-x^4\right)^{n-1}$.
Then they ask to use the last expression to calculate $\displaystyle\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{n}{2^n}$.
Thanks!

Comment: did you check out any suggestions at the bottom right corner of the screen?

Comment: "It gave me..." What is "it?" I think that's the power series for $$\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2}$$, assume you change it to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: The series you give is not (explicitly) a power series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n=\frac{1}{1-y}\quad;\quad\text{for}\ |y|<1.\tag1
$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $y$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty ny^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}.\tag2
$$
Multiplying $(2)$ by $y$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty ny^{n}=\frac{y}{(1-y)^2}.\tag3
$$
Now plug in $y=\dfrac12$ to $(3)$ yields
$$
\large\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{2}{(2-1)^2}=2}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version without using power series:

Let $A$ = 1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 + 4/16 + .... =

(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...) + (0/2 + 1/4 + 2/8 + 3/16 + ... ) = 1 + $A/2$.

Solving gives  $A = 2 $

Comment: Could you explain it better?

Comment: 1/2 = 1/2 + 0/2; 2/4 = 1/4 + 1/4; 3/8 = 1/8 + 2/8; 4/16 = 1/16 + 3/16; 5/32 = 1/32 + 4/32; etc.  Group together the 1/2^n terms, that sums to 1 by geometric series. The remaining terms (the second parentheses) form a series which is exactly 1/2 of the original series [just compare it to the original in the top line], and so its sum is A/2. So A = 1 + A/2, solve for A.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 2\neq 1$

Comment: the first term of the series you wrote is 1/2, not 1.

Comment: correct, sorry.